# How to setup connection via VPN to private AKS

Tags: azure, private, azure-aks, openvpn

I am trying to setup a private AKS cluster which I want to manage from a user laptop using kubectl. I have tried to create a simple setup with one vNET, Azure VPN gateway with OpenVPN configuration, where the VPN Gateway is attached to one subnet of the vNET and AKS is configured via Azure CNI to live in another subnet of the same vNET. I have expected that this is all I would need to get manage the cluster as long as I am connected to the VPN (I understood that all subnets on a vNET are routed by default). But when I try to use kubectl I get **Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup : no such host** My network knowledge does not go too deep unfortunately, but should this just work? I mean it all lives within the same vNET. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My setup is very similar and I ran into the same situation. This was a DNS issue for me.

If you have a private DNS zone with your private AKS cluster (should be in the resource group which was created for the AKS private cluster), go find the DNS record and IP address for the API server. Put that IP address into your hosts file (/etc/hosts if on linux or WSL) with the fully qualified domain name, then try your kubectl commands again.